# Why doesn't common c++ compiler optimize away object copy?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++14

I have the source below:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    int data[10000]; // A large data field
    void print() const{
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            std::cout<<data[i]<<",";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
};
struct B{
    A data;
    void print() const{
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            std::cout<<data.data[i]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
};


int main(){
    A a;
    a.data[50]=10;
    a.data[60]=5;
    a.data[70]=3;
    a.print();
    B b{a};
    b.print();          
}
```

It holds a large data field in A, puts it into B and then executes its member function. Now, since B does not have any other data field than A, I think the compiler could actually optimize away the copy and just reuse the same data block, executing different member functions. However, according to https://godbolt.org/g/21z7TT, neither the latest version of g++ nor clang with `-O3` compile option optimizes the `memcpy` away. Is there a reason why this code cannot be optimized, and is there a way to let the compiler optimize it?

Comment: There's already syntax to express what you want: references.  Make B::data a reference to A, and everything will work fine.  It will also make explicit the need to independently ensure that `a` outlives `b`

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to return the struct from a function.

Comment: @eivour Objects owning references to other objects is bad advice anyhow. A better bet here is to simply make `print` a free function that accepts a `const A&`. Classes are supposed to encapsulate data, if `B` is not encapsulating any data of its own there's no reason for it to exist here.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want A to be tracked via a pointer.  If you want that data block to be shared, then you want a `std::shared_ptr`.  But none of this is really what your question is.  If you are looking for solutions to an architectural problem, you'll want to ask a different question, and be complete about what your use case is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't optimize away the copy because you have literally instructed it to make a copy.  `struct B { A data; ... };` says that B contains its own copy of an A structure.

In this particular minature program, a compiler could theoretically use the same memory without consequence.  However, that ability goes away if any of a number of things change:

- `a` is used again
- `B` contains any data members other than `A`
- `b` is passed to another function
- others I haven't thought of.

Given how rare the conditions for this optimization are, I'm not surprised there is no special compiler case for it.